# tail-recursive function in self-defined list_t

Tags: c++, recursion, tail-recursion

I am working on a project based on a custom-defined data structure list_t in C++.
Here is the predefined functions that would help me manipulate this list_t and the function I am asked to write which is called insert_list(list_t, list_t, int) is to be tail-recursive.

```
typedef Recursive_list list_t;

// EFFECTS: returns true if list is empty, false otherwise
bool list_isEmpty(const list_t& list);

// EFFECTS: returns an empty list.
list_t list_make();

// EFFECTS: given the list (list) make a new list consisting of
//          the new element followed by the elements of the
//          original list. 
list_t list_make(int elt, const list_t& list);

// REQUIRES: list is not empty
// EFFECTS: returns the first element of list
int list_first(const list_t& list);

// REQUIRES: list is not empty
// EFFECTS: returns the list containing all but the first element of list
list_t list_rest(const list_t& list);

// MODIFIES: cout
// EFFECTS: prints list to cout.
void list_print(const list_t& list);
```

The insert_list() function I am to write takes in two inputs both of type list_t and an additional integer n that is guaranteed not greater than the size of the first list_t and returns another list_t that contains the first n elements from the first list_t (in the order they appear in the original list_t), followed by the entire second list_t and then followed by the remaining elements (integers) of the first list_t. The constraint is that this function, and its helper functions if any, must be tail-recursive. See the prototype for insert_list() here:

```
/*
 * REQUIRES: n >= 0 and n <= the number of elements in first
 * EFFECTS: returns a list comprising the first n elements of
 *          "first", followed by all elements of "second",
 *           followed by any remaining elements of "first".
 *
 *     For example: insert (( 1 2 3 ), ( 4 5 6 ), 2)
 *            is  ( 1 2 4 5 6 3 ).
 */
list_t insert_list(list_t first, list_t second, int n);
```

I have spent days thinking and trying out ways to attack this but the furthest I got would have the first n numbers reversed. I did write a function that reverse a list_t but I wouldn't be able to reverse part of a list, only reversing an entire list is possible and it wouldn't fit into the tail-recursion structure I've come up with. I also wondered if I need to write two recursively functions that actually depend on each other but haven't come up with any useful solution down that road either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep adding elements from the first list and decrementing `n` until it reaches zero. Then you need to keep adding elements from the second list until it is exhausted, and finally append the rest of the first list.

**EDIT:** the above description does not achieve tail-recursion. I have modified the implementation as a result. The approach is: while `n` is above zero, keep taking elements off the front of `first` and pre-pending them to `second`, while decrementing `n`. When `n` reaches zero, do the opposite: keep taking elements off the front of `second` and pre-pending them to `first`, until `second` is empty. This achieves a full tail-recursive implementation.

```
list_t insert_list(list_t first, list_t second, int n)
{
    if(n==0) {
        if(list_isEmpty(second))
            return first;
        else 
            return insert_list(list_make(list_first(second), first), list_rest(second), 0);
    }
    else {
        return insert_list(list_rest(first), list_make(list_first(first), second), n-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `list_first(second)` is incompatible with the first parameter type of `list_make`

Comment: No it isn't. First parameter of `list_make` takes a single element. The return type of `list_first` is a single element

Comment: @Smeehey your solution does not meet the constraint- it is not tail-recursive. The return list_make() statement leaves pending work (call function list_make()) after we make call to insert_list() function. Do you have another solution that is tail-recursive?

Comment: I've modified the solution in the answer to address this.

Comment: @Smeeheey your solution is now tail-recursive but it's buggy... Take L1 = (1 2 3), L2 = (4 5 6) for example, your insert_list(L1, L2, 1) gives the output (6 5 4 1 2 3) which differs from the correct ontput (1 4 5 6 2 3)